# Redirect me to :[port]/[whatever I type]

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an app running on `localhost:8080` , I configured Nginix to make it run on `localhost/`

And I have another app running on `localhost:3000`

What I want to do is to redirect me to `localhost:3000/[whatever]` when I originally go to `localhost/[whatever]`

I wanna do something similar to this:

```
location /[SOMETHING] {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/[THAT_SAME_THING_ABOVE];
}
```

Is it possible to configure Nginx to do this behavior? if so how?
Thanks

PS: The app running on `:8080` is a single page so `:8080/[whatever]` doesn't even exist now

Comment: You're looking for a [reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) or a normal [rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, just in case somebody needs it

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000
}
```